# Html file structure best-practice?

Tags: html, web

I want to make a simple little website, but I'm honestly not quite sure about how to structure the files.
To display a html-page under the link

> samplesite.com/test

should I rather use:

> main/test/index.html

Or:

> main/test.html

Answer (score 2):

Regardless the domain, the web browser will always look for the `index.html` of your project. So the `domain.com/index.html` is the way to go.

Answering the question based from the title. For `html file structure`, it is good to have the index.html on your root/project directory this:

[image]

Putting other `web assets` in different directory will help you to have a better file organization, you can also download some design/templating framework like [zurb foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) and check the file structure.

Comment: I found this example structure helpful. Also checking for a framework structure is one way to have an insights how other developer/groups create their workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The main page (opening page ) should be `index.html` coz when you upload it on `apache /public_html` folder by default it looks for `index.html` (or php in case you use php) so if your website is `www.dummy.com` ,by default when you go on it it serves `index.html` and to get `test.html` you have to use `www.dummy.com/test.html`